# How to access pthread api with project-panama

Tags: java, project-panama

I've been experimenting the early builds of project-panama and successfully run some of the examples.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to interact with native pthread api due to internal exceptions.

Here is what I tried:

```
jextract \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED" \
    --exclude-symbols "PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS" \
    /usr/include/pthread.h -t unix.pthread -o pthread.jar
```

```
...
var t = Libraries.bind(MethodHandles.lookup(), pthread.class);
```

the above snippet throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser$InvalidDescriptorException: Illegal char in ident: [u32(__low)u32(__high)](ano
n$thread-_shared-types_h$6259
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser$DescriptorScanner.error(DescriptorParser.java:538)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser.parseIdent(DescriptorParser.java:370)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser.parseAnnotation(DescriptorParser.java:229)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser.annotationsOpt(DescriptorParser.java:220)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser.annotatedOpt(DescriptorParser.java:214)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser.parseGroup(DescriptorParser.java:305)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.memory.DescriptorParser.parseLayout(DescriptorParser.java:99)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.Util.layoutof(Util.java:154)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver.addNameIfNeeded(LayoutResolver.java:89)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver.addClass(LayoutResolver.java:73)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver.addClass(LayoutResolver.java:82)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver.addClass(LayoutResolver.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver.addClass(LayoutResolver.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver.<init>(LayoutResolver.java:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver$1.computeValue(LayoutResolver.java:60)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver$1.computeValue(LayoutResolver.java:57)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:226)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:208)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:114)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LayoutResolver.get(LayoutResolver.java:68)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.BinderClassGenerator.<init>(BinderClassGenerator.java:92)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.HeaderImplGenerator.<init>(HeaderImplGenerator.java:80)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LibrariesHelper$3.computeValue(LibrariesHelper.java:133)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LibrariesHelper$3.computeValue(LibrariesHelper.java:126)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromHashMap(ClassValue.java:226)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.getFromBackup(ClassValue.java:208)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassValue.get(ClassValue.java:114)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LibrariesHelper.getHeaderImplClass(LibrariesHelper.java:157)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LibrariesHelper.bind(LibrariesHelper.java:256)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.foreign.LibrariesHelper.bind(LibrariesHelper.java:275)
        at java.base/java.foreign.Libraries.bind(Libraries.java:63)
```

Am I missing something or pthread is not supported by the project?

Comment: Haven't tried to build a newer version to verify, but this may be related
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223947

Comment: I think you've found the culprit. FWIW, short of building the JDK yourself, you can get Panama nightlies for x86_64 Linux at: https://builds.shipilev.net/openjdk-panama/ as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know about these nightly builds.
I think there's a regression though. jextract fails to build the library:  https://pastebin.com/5RrEwNGU